# When using a 12 column grid whenever I put tags inside an element like <header> <div> whatever the descendent elements are

Tags: css, header, grid, display, lwp-useragent

I'm new to coding and trying to get into using grids in my css as they seem super useful.  My textbook and all the guides I find tend to show the css but not associated html.

Anyway when I put tags into and area element like   , the tags inside of them will not display in the correct columns and rows, but if I take those tags out of those elements they will work in the grid.  Using the inspect tool tells me to turn the parent element to display: grid, but that doesen't work.  My textbook says you can use `<div>`, `<article>` etc etc on a 12 column grid but for the life of me I can't figure it out.

I've tried putting display: grid into every element... I've tried using the inspect tool to try to learn why they are getting the display: block property, but all I get is its coming from "user agent stylesheet", Ive tried on Chrome and Firefox.

```css
/* custom property */
:root {
    --global-color-1: #21aab4;
    background-color: white;
}
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

/* the styles for the elements */
body {
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
    
    border: 3px solid black;

    margin: 0;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-rows: 150px auto auto 150px;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 8.3vw);
    
}
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#logo{
    display: grid;
    grid-row: 1 /2; grid-column: 1 / 5;
    max-width: 100%;    
}
#name{
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-top: 2rem;
    grid-row: 1 /2; grid-column: 1 / 5;
}
#header {
    grid-row: 1 / 2; grid-column: 1 / 13;
    background-color: white;
  border-bottom: 2px solid black;
}
#nav {  
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;

  list-style-type: none;
  grid-column: 5 / 12;
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
    border-bottom: 2px solid black;

}
main {
    grid-row: 2 / 4; grid-column: 1 / 13;
    display: grid;
}



#thoughtful {
  display: flex;
    grid-row: 2 / 4;
    grid-column: 1 /  5;
}
#s2 {
    grid-row: 2 / 4; grid-column: 7 / 13;
    width: 40vw;
}
#s2 h1{
    font-size: 3.2vw;
}
#s2 li{
    font-size: 2vw;
}
footer {
    grid-row: 4 / 5; grid-column: 1 / 12;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 5vh;
    font-family: serif;
}
a:focus, a:hover {
    font-style: italic;
}

.current {
    color:  rgb(20, 111, 4);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Sage Raymond </title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="images/Bear-favicon.jpg">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/main_gridexp.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
</head>

<body>
        <div id="logo"><a href="index.html"><img src="images/name.gif" alt="Sage Raymond Homepage" id="name"></a></div>
        <ul id="nav">
      <li> </li>
      <li class="current"><a href="index.html"><h2>Home</h2></a></li>

      <li><a href="education.html"><h2 class="current">C.V.</h2></a></li>
      <li><a href="publications.html"><h2>Papers</h2></a></li>
      <li><a href="media.html"><h2>Media</h2></a></li>
    </ul>

    <img src="images/thoughtful_sage.jpeg" id="thoughtful">
    <ul id="s2">
      <h1>Degrees</h1>
      <li>Master of Science in Ecology, University of Alberta, January 2021 to present</li>
      <li>Bachelor of Science in Biology, Thompson Rivers University, December 2020</li>
      <li>Diploma in Recreation, Fish, and Wildlife, Selkirk College, April 2017</li>   
    </ul>

    <footer>
      <p>&copy; 2022, Sage Raymond, Port Townsend, WA, USA 98368</p>
    </footer>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I convert your code into snippet. Can you check about it and be sure it correspond to what you have ? Because the `styles/main_gridexp.css` is missing, so some css rules will be missing

Comment: You have elements with grid properties set on them, which also have `display:flex` on them too, this will over-ride any other `display` properties in the natural cascade. More info here on this concept: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Cascade